# How to get JSON data from Angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have an user login..

```
this.logincheck = function(log) {           
          var parameter ={
                    "mail" :log.mail,
                    "password" :log.passwords
                    }  
            alert(JSON.stringify(parameter));
            $http({
                url: '---------',
               -----------
            }).success(function(data,status) {
            if(data.status=="success")  {   
                var sessionid = data.member.member_id; //Member JSON is defined below
                $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {userid: sessionid}); // How to pass entire object to user dashboard
            }
            else{
                alert("Invalid Username or Password try again. !!!");
            }
            }); 
    };
```

I not only want member ID I want entire data present in the member....
I have the following controller :

```
.state('dashboardsnew', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboardsnew",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content-empty.html",
        })

        .state('dashboardsnew.dashboardefault', {
            url: "/dashboardefault",
            templateUrl: "views/userdashboard.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Hive Dashboard',specialClass: 'loginscreen-gray-bg' },           
        })
```

I have the following JSON data from web service.( After user logged in I get this JSON data).

```
{
  "member": {
    "member_id": 51,
    "first_name": "Deepak",
    "last_name": "Verma",
    "phone": 6886438910,
    "password": "sushil",
    "role": [
      {
        "role_id": 2,
        "name": "Society Admin"
      }
    ],
    "associated": []
  },
  "society": {
    "society_id": 10,
    "society_name": "Green Velley"
  },
  "status": "success",
  "message": "member data details !"
}
```

Above JSON data has to be displayed in login home page. While using normal angular JS I supposed to use this :

```
$http.get('http://192.168.1.7:8080/apartment//member/details/' + myParamtr).then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.member;
}
```

In front end I supposed :

```
{{myData.user_name}}
```

Comment: what's the issue? and where's `user_name` in your `myData`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to persist data from one state to another, in this case I recommend using an angular service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

You can create a memberService, set the member data to the service, redirect the user, and retrieve the member data from the service in your next controller.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. The site you mentioned it may be temporary down.. Can you suggest me more. Or this is enough : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp

Comment: That w3 article doesnt seem to explain it well. This article by John Papa (angular prodigy) explains it well: https://johnpapa.net/sharing-data-in-an-angular-controller-or-an-angular-service/

Also a more hands on example: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/hu1/wiki/2.2-Intro-to-Using-An-AngularJS-Service-to-Manage-Data

Answer (score 0):

```
url : your json file location with respect to your index file.
 $http.get(url).success(function(response) { 
       $scope.myData = response.member; // Your member data
       $scope.myData1 = response.member.first_name; // Your member firstName
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Am using Angular framework.. How to pass json object to the controller.?

Comment: "response" is your data of json, so by getting response means you are getting object of json in your controller.